# Find the two variable Maclaurin series for $f(x,y) = e^{x+y}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm shaky with Taylor/Maclaurin series, and I've been over and over my book and notes and still feel like I'm at square one...

Comment: Find the partial derivatives first.

Comment: Alright... f_x = xe^(x+y)
f_y = ye^(x+y)... right?

Comment: Hint: $e^{x+y}=e^x\,e^y$

Comment: for f_x I get (e^x)(e^y).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still very lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $f(x,y) = f(x+y,0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x+y)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n!} \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$.

From this, we can read off the $x^i y^j$ term coefficient as $\frac{1}{(i+j)!} \binom{j+i}{i} = \frac{1}{i!} \frac{1}{j!}$ (by letting $(i,j) = (k,n-k)$ and solving for $k,n$ in terms of $i,j$).

Answer (score 0):

You can write $f(x,y)=\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {x^i}{i!}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {y^j}{j!}$ and multiply term by term